# I am not getting how to add properties in a cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my Property controller:

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_property, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :contact_now]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    if params[:search].present?
      search_term = "%#{params[:search]}%"
      @properties = Property.where('name LIKE ? OR city LIKE ?', search_term, search_term).page(params[:page]).per(3)
    else
      @properties = Property.all.page(params[:page]).per(3)
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @property = Property.new
  end

  def create
    @property = Property.new(property_params)
    @property.user_id = current_user.id

    if @property.save
      redirect_to properties_path, notice: "Property created successfully!!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @property.update(property_params)
      redirect_to properties_path, notice: "Property updated successfully!!"
    else
      render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def button_click_action
    @user = current_user
    UserMailer.button_click_email(@user).deliver_now
    redirect_to properties_path, notice: 'Email sent!'
  end

  def destroy
    @property.destroy
    redirect_to properties_path, notice: "Property Deleted!!", status: :see_other
  end

  private

  def set_property
    @property = Property.find(params[:id])
  end

  def property_params
    params.require(:property).permit(:name, :city, :country, :price, :status, :year, images: [])
  end
end
```

It is creating properties and showing them, but now I want to add these property to a cart.
Please explain how can I approach to create a cart

Comment: You need to add more information to your question, what specifically is a cart and/or a property. How're they related and what means for you "to add properties in a cart".

Comment: User and Property are two models that have association with Cart as
Cart belongs to user
Cart has_many properties,

My question is how can I add properties to the cart.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in three ways.

1. Attach the cart at the time of property creation by just adding the cart_id (just like you attached user in the create action - you need to figure out which car it has to be attached)
2. You can make use of the update method, pass cart_id in property_params.
3. You can define another action (say, def assign_cart and do the cart_id update)